# Empty line rendered in UINavigationBar with UISearchController in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios11, uisearchcontroller

This is most likely to be an iOS bug, I've reported to Apple already (35410538) but I'd like to find a workaround to temporary fix it.

When you have an UITableViewController inside UITabBarController which is embedded by UINavigationController an empty line is rendered when scrolling. This happens on both simulator and device. the navigation controller has to be set to show iOS 11's large titles and have an UISearchController in it.

I've setup a sample project demonstrating it [here](https://github.com/diegotrevisan/iOS11LargeTitleSearchBarBug).

Has anyone found a workaround to fill that line?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: simulater size increase to 1x after test

Comment: @SagarBhut ????

Comment: Running your code, I only see the problem when running on a simulator that has been resized to a smaller size. It looks like it is probably a side-effect of the resizing.

Comment: Maybe it's not visible on full size simulator but it's visible on device. Happens to me and my app's users. One of them reviewed 4/5 just because of this glitch.

Comment: I've updated the original post demonstrating on a real device.